# Eigenvector and eigenvalue of the differential operator $L(x)=x''+3x'-4x$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, differential-operators

This is a follow up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349098/finding-the-kernel-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-the-operator-lx-x) one.

Just to summarize. I want to find the kernel, eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the differential operator:

$$L(x):=x''+3x'-4x$$

In other words I want to find the eigenvalue and eigenvector solutions to $$Lx=\lambda x$$

I can write:

$$x''+3x'-4x=\lambda x \iff x''+3x'-(4+\lambda)x$$

I can factorize the characteristic Polynomial $p_{\lambda}$ to get the eigenvalues:

$$p_{\lambda}=x^2+3x-(4+\lambda)$$

The roots of this polynomial are:

$$\frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{25+4\lambda}}{2}$$

Therefore the general solution is:

$$x(t)=c_1 e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{25+4\lambda}+3)t}+c_2 e^{\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{25+4\lambda}-3)t}$$

The kernel is the solution to the equation $Lx=0$. Substituting $\lambda=0$ into my equation yields:

$$\ker(L)=c_1e^{-4t}+c_2e^{t}$$

**My question:** For the general solution, do I have to check what happens when $25+4\lambda \le 0$ i.e when the radicand is zero or negative. Will that change my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case $\lambda<-\frac{25}{4}$ you can keep the notation, if you allow the use of complex exponential. If you want to stick to real functions - which might be the case, seeing that the problem wants you to work in $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ - you can use real and imaginary part of the complex exponential, writing the eigenvectors as:
$$x(t)=e^{-\frac32t}\left(c_1\sin\left(t\sqrt{-\lambda-\frac{25}{4}}\right)+c_2\cos\left(t\sqrt{-\lambda-\frac{25}{4}}\right)\right)$$

For the case $\lambda=-\frac{25}{4}$, the eigenvectors are
$$x(t)=(c_1t+c_2)e^{-\frac32t}$$

The last case cannot be put in the same notation you used for the case $\lambda>-\frac{25}{4}$, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you maybe expand on how you got to the solution for $ \lambda < -\frac{25}{4}$? What do you mean when you say "the last case cannot be put in the same notation you used for $\lambda >0$". Are you referring to the case $\lambda=0$?

Comment: It was a typo. I fixed it. The formulas I used come from the general solution of $n$-th order ODE with constant coefficients. With a quick search on the internet, I found [this source](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-2ndOrderLinearEqns_Stu.pdf) explaining the case $n=2$.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the link. Looks like a lot of useful information on that site. Thanks again.